# arraylist and array with different order

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I have arraylist with content

```
array1={2,3,6,5,4}
```

and `array[]` with content

```
array2={4,5}
```

I want to store the same element of these two arrays in another one. But in same `array2[]` order.

```
List<controllers> array1 = new ArrayList<controllers>();
SocketAddress [] array2 = new  SocketAddress[2];
for (int g = 0; g < array2.length; g++) {

    for (int v = 0; v < array1.size(); v++){
        if (array1.get(v).equals(array2[g]) ){
             array3.add(array1.get(v));
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be `{5,4}`, while I want store the result with the same `array2` order `{4,5}`.

Comment: `array1.get(v).equals(array2[g])`: `controllers` is a different type to `SocketAddress` (unless there's some inheritance you're not mentioning?)

Comment: yes. it is with different type. there's inheritance in my project.

Comment: Is it the case that you want the natural ordering of the elements at all times?

Comment: No, I want as array2 element order.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should use `ArrayList` instead of array in Java. You have better api and dynamic resizing.

You can convert an array to List with

```
List<TypeOfYourObject> newAwesomeList = Arrays.asList(oldArray);
```

When you will have both arrays converted to lists you could simply do

```
listA.removeAll(new HashSet(listB));
```

Be aware that result will be in `listA`. If you want to have old contents of `listA` you should copy that list

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: But I want the result as array1 type. list of object. :\ NOT as array2 type

Comment: If you want to have typed list you should use List<TypeOfYourObject> newAwesomeList = Arrays.asList(oldArray);

Answer (score 0):

I create the program from your code and executed it. It returning the correct output as you expect. I have converted your `SocketAddress` to `Integer` array. I assumed you `array3` will be of `List` type, as you mentioned `add()` operation on it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TreeToMap {
  static List<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  static Integer array2[] = new Integer[]{4,5};
  static List<Integer> array3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public static void method() {
    for (int g = 0; g < array2.length; g++) {
      for (int v = 0; v < array1.size(); v++) {
        if (array1.get(v).equals(array2[g])) {
          array3.add(array1.get(v));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    array1.add(2);
    array1.add(3);
    array1.add(6);
    array1.add(5);
    array1.add(4);
    method();
    for (Integer i : array3) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }    
  }
}
```

---

**Output:**
4
5

Comment: it is still doing that. I have taken the code from your question. `if (array1.get(v).equals(array2[g])) {
          array3.add(array1.get(v));
        }`.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario is that both `arrayList1` and `array2` are large, and `array2` contain duplicates, and you want the result as an array, not a list (`array3`).

To optimize the lookups into `arrayList1`, you convert the list into a `Set`. This works as long as the object added to the set implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

```
List<Integer> arrayList1 = null/*defined elsewhere*/;
Integer[] array2 = null/*defined elsewhere*/;

Set<Integer> valuesToKeep = new HashSet<>(arrayList1);
List<Integer> keptValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer value : array2)
    if (valuesToKeep.contains(value))
        keptValues.add(value);
Integer[] array3 = keptValues.toArray(new Integer[keptValues.size()]);
```

This follows the example of your text. Replace `Integer` to fit the needs of your code example.